# Cannot convert ZoneConfiguration to ZoneOptions

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

As `ZoneOptions` is deprecated, I changed `optionsByRecordZoneID` variable to `ZoneConfiguration` as follows

```
   var optionsByRecordZoneID = [CKRecordZone.ID: CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.ZoneConfiguration]()

   for zoneID in zoneIDs {
            let options = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.ZoneConfiguration()
            options.previousServerChangeToken = settings.getChangeToken(forKey: databaseTokenKey)
            optionsByRecordZoneID[zoneID] = options
        }
```

Now, I am getting the following error for this line for `optionsByRecordZoneID` variable,

```
let fetchRecordZoneChangesOperation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: zoneIDs, optionsByRecordZoneID: optionsByRecordZoneID)
```

> Cannot convert value of type '[CKRecordZone.ID :
>   CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.ZoneConfiguration]' to expected
>   argument type '[CKRecordZone.ID :
>   CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.ZoneOptions]?'

Any help in regard to get rid of it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `init(recordZoneIDs:,optionsByRecordZoneID:)` is deprecated too since it takes the old `ZoneOptions`.

Use `init(recordZoneIDs:,configurationsByRecordZoneID:)`.

```
let fetchRecordZoneChangesOperation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: zoneIDs, configurationsByRecordZoneID: optionsByRecordZoneID)
```

Comment: This is the real answer. This is the way to do it in Xcode 10.2

Answer (score 0):

Just add this entry to state that the accepted answer it is **the way** to do it in Xcode 10.2. Please take a look at it.